# How to fix Admob ads in listview

Tags: java, android, android-listview, admob

I have build an android app , this app is news app , I fetched data in json view , now I want to add a ads in every 3 items below , now after trying some days successfully shows ads. my listview 5 number of data , ads showing number of data show in 4 , now i want to show all number of data and every three items below ads

```
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


    if ((i + 1) / 3 == 1){

        View ad_view=LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.ad_layout,viewGroup,false);

        AdView  mAdView = ad_view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        return ad_view;


    } else {


        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.model_result, viewGroup, false);
        }


        TextView match_h = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.heding);

        User user = (User) this.getItem(i);

        final String mach_hed = user.getMathch_hed();
        match_h.setText(mach_hed);
       return view;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `(i + 1) / 3 == 1)` try `(i + 1) % 4 == 0)`
If will show ads, every 4th time. That means, after every 3 item, one ad will be shown.

Comment: oky now working........... but my app show 5 data now add this code show only 4 data and one ads , i want to show all data and adview

Comment: instead of `User user = (User) this.getItem(i);` try `User user = (User) this.getItem(i-(int)(i+1)/4);`

Comment: because you have added a List to populate, but trying to show more items that the list actually has. but the adapter only generates view for how many list items you have. You can add some extra dummy items to your list to avoid this